# Global Pointer Memeory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, global-variables

I want to clear my basics about global pointer memory, Can some body help me to understand the memory impact of a Global constant;

```
// This is define out of interface on top of .m file
NSString *const kXyz  = @"xyz";
```

Does it impact memory usage, why I am asking this because I may or may not use this constant so I am thinking of having a MACRO

```
#define G_XYZ @"xyz"
```

and use this *inside an if statement* instead of global constant to save memory, As MACRO will be removed at compile time I will save some memory.

Is my understanding correct about MACROS and Global const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation is to use the constant. Unless you are in a very memory constrained environment the wasted memory if you don't use it is minute. The frameworks are full of such constants.

However to aid understanding: the constant will use memory for the string itself and one pointer sized chunk of memory for the constant's own storage - typically 4 or 8 bytes. Unless that is you don't use it and the compiler or linker is able to remove it; this is unlikely if the constant is globally accessible, more likely if it is a file scope (static) constant. The memory usage of the macro is also compiler/linker dependant, but probably more than the constant - consider that after macro processing the compiler sees multiple uses of the same literal string, possibly in different files.

So unless you know your compiler/linker well, and it doesn't change, then you are considering likelihoods:

1. The constant will more than likely consume a small fixed amount of memory.
2. If not used the macro will consume no memory.
3. If used exactly once the macro will consume about the same memory as the constant, the difference, if any, will be negligible.
4. If used more than once in the same file the macro may use more memory.
5. If used more than once in more than one file the macro will probably use more memory.

In summary, if the string is used the constant will probably use less memory and at most a negligible amount more, so don't worry about it unless you are very memory constrained; or until memory becomes an issue. But understanding is good!

Answer (score 0):

No, using a macro like:

```
#define G_XYZ @"xyz"
NSString *s = G_XYZ;
```

Will be preprocessed to:

```
NSString *s = @"xyz";
```

So the two will be identical after the preprocessing step.

If you want to see what your code is being preprocessed to, try `gcc -E myfile.c`

You could possible write in a header:

```
extern NSString *g_xyz;
```

And in one source file:

```
NSString *g_xyz = @"xyz";
```

And in other source files you can use this value:

```
NSLog(g_xyz);
```

However this is really not worth thinking about unless the string is huge or there are a lot of them. Even an empty program will probably be several KB, so shaving off a few bytes is really not necessary except in extreme circumstances (in which you probably won't be using Objective C).

Comment: use this MACRO *inside an if statement* instead of global constant to save memory, As MACRO will be removed at compile time I will save some memory. Is it worth doing on iOS platform as these are 30/40 strings with 30 to 100 chars each (Total 2 to 4 KB in just one file)

Comment: @MadhuS.Kapoor - you will only save memory if the string literal is removed at compile time, and that is only likely if you never use the macro. Indeed using the macro may increase memory use.